# How to share a tHashInput between jobs?

Tags: talend

I want to feed a tHashInput with a lot of data. I want to use the Hash in subjobs to have some modularity in my master job. I know how to share simple data using context variables, but I would like to know how to share this object to use it as tHashOutput. Or maybe there is another way to do it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As garpitmzn points out the tHash components are private to the job and so cannot be shared across the job.

To share data between jobs you can use the tBuffer components to move data back up to a parent job or of course write the data to a flat file or database.

If performance is a concern you could try using an in memory database such as [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) to temporarily hold the data.

Alternatively you could merge all of the jobs into a single job assuming that it doesn't then exceed the maximum amount of components for a job. This has a lot of obvious drawbacks and means your job complexity becomes very high but it would allow you to carry on using your tHash components.

Comment: The tBuffer is very slow. What I'm trying to achieve with tHash is performance. In the end I'm using a big job with tHashOutput and tHashInputs repeated everywhere. About your proposal to use in-memory database, it sounds interesting. But I believe this belongs to another question

Answer (score 0):

tHash works for sharing data within the job. For sharing data across sub-jobs you should use tBufferOutput/tBufferInput.

Comment: I believe there must be a way. A buffer is not what I'm looking for because the data contained in the hash is huge. I only need the object reference.

Comment: if data volume is huge, you can use flat files for sharing data across subjobs, or your requirement is to use tHash only?

Comment: I need to use a hash because I have to do intensive calculations with the minimum access time to the data and I have to access the data many times. So, I'm looking for extreme performance.